# System32 to file is corrupt or missing

Tags: windows-xp

Windows XP-7493 cannot start because System32/corrupt or missing. It says i need the original windows utilities driver CD. Which of course I do not have. Can u help me?

Comment: This does not fit the question/answer format of this site.  Please see the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Without an XP CD to repair it, you're out of luck unless the machine in question happens to have a recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recovery/restore CD or pen drive ... assuming other means for instance restarting in safe mode also have failed.. as a rule of thumb - Backup!